# Mongo find by sum of subdoc array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to find stocks in the `Stock` collection where the sum of all owners' shares is less than 100. Here is my schema.

```
const stockSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  owners: [
    {
      owner: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Owner"
      },
      shares: {
          type: Number,
          min: 0,
          max: 100
      }
    }
  ]
}

const Stock = mongoose.model("Stock", stockSchema);
```

I've tried to use `aggregate` but it returns a single object computed over all stocks in the collection, as opposed to multiple objects with the sum of *each* stock's shares.

```
stockSchema.statics.getUnderfundedStocks = async () => {
  const result = await Stock.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$owners" },
    { $group: { _id: null, shares: { $sum: "$owners.shares" } } },
    { $match: { shares: { $lt: 100 } } }
  ]);
  return result;
};
```

So, rather than getting:

`[ { _id: null, shares: 150 } ]` from `getUnderfundedStocks`, I'm looking to get:

`[ { _id: null, shares: 90 }, { _id: null, shares: 60 } ]`.

I've come across `$expr`, which looks useful, but documentation is scarce and not sure if that's the appropriate path to take.

---

Edit: Some document examples:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea699fb201db57b8e4e2e8a"),
    "owners" : [ 
        {
            "owner" : ObjectId("5ea62a94ccb1b974d40a2c72"),
            "shares" : 85
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea699fb201db57b8e4e2e1e"),
    "owners" : [ 
        {
            "owner" : ObjectId("5ea62a94ccb1b974d40a2c72"),
            "shares" : 20
        }, 
        {
            "owner" : ObjectId("5ea62a94ccb1b974d40a2c73"),
            "shares" : 50
        }, 
        {
            "owner" : ObjectId("5ea62a94ccb1b974d40a2c74"),
            "shares" : 30
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to return an array that just includes document #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `$group` here. Simply use `$project` with `$sum` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "shares": { "$sum": "$owners.shares" }   
  }},
  { "$match": { "shares": { "$lt": 100 } } }
])
```

Or even you do not need to use aggregation here

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": { "$lt": [{ "$sum": "$owners.shares" }, 100] }
})
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wRkqkaTzO-J)

Comment: Your second solution is far more preferable because it returns the original schema, rather than adding a new `shares` property as the first solution does, which is troublesome when combining with other documents of the same collection. Brilliant!